# Python for loop only recognizing first line of the block

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, anaconda, spyder

I am new to Python. I am using python 3 for a simple Machine Learning project in Anaconda Spyder IDE.
I tried to take input a csv file name and add those in a pandas dataframe one by one using a for loop:

```
for i in range (var):
    name = input ('CSV file name: ')
    data = pd.read_csv (name)
    stocks = pd.DataFrame ({name: data ['Column name']})
```

The problem is, the for loop is working only for the first line. It takes input of the file names one after another "var" times, then read only the last file.
Why the for loop is working like this? What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're overwriting the variables every time through the loop. Also, putting spaces before the parentheses is not good Python style (it's not good style in any language that I know of, come to think of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new dataframe in each iteration of your loop. Instead, the Pandas approach [as recommended in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is to construct a dataframe from an iterable of series:

```
d = {}
for i in range(var):
    name = input('CSV file name: ')
    data = pd.read_csv(name)
    d[name] = data['Column name']

stocks = pd.concat(d.values(), axis=1, keys=d)
```